# Tracking unique user logins with Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, grafana, promql

I currently run a ShinyProxy (SP) application and want to track users login and present it in Grafana as `Unique user per selected time period`.

A Prometheus server is already collecting metrics from SP but does not by default track the above mentioned.
I´m not too sure which metric type (and query) to use or whether Prometheus is the appropriate backend.

Comment: Did you make any progress with this?

Comment: unfortunately no, sorry. I switched to influxDB which seems to be easy integratable as a push service into ShinyProxy.